# Postfix SASL with Dovecot and Authenticated Smarthost

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, dovecot, smarthost

I have a bit of a problem;
I have configured postfix to use dovecot for SMTP AUTH, therefore I had to specify dovecot authentication in the main.cf file. The problem is, I need to also authenticate to my smarthost for outgoing SMTP relaying. I can't seem to do both at once. I can either configure my smart host, or I can configure dovecot auth.

main.cf file:

```
relayhost = relay.jangosmtp.net:2525
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_passwd

smtp_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/certs/key.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/certs/cert.pem
```

I tried to combine the two together, but postfix will not send mail via the smarthost, although it will still authenticate SMTP submission users.

maillog gives the following error:

```
Sep 16 23:59:00 hg-gv postfix/smtp[16631]: warning: unsupported SASL client implementation: dovecot
Sep 16 23:59:00 hg-gv postfix/smtp[16631]: fatal: SASL library initialization
```

This makes sense, but I need to have dovecot enabled to authenticate SMTP users.

I have no idea what to do about this.

Comment: *smtp != smtpd*. Replace `smtp_sasl_type` with `smtpd_sasl_type` and try to send email again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** smtp != smtpd

- [smtp act as *smtp client*](http://www.postfix.org/lmtp.8.html) used to sending email
- [smtpd act as *smtp server*](http://www.postfix.org/smtpd.8.html) used to receiving email

Parameter `smtp_sasl_type` with dovecot was unsupported. Maybe you mean `smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot` instead.